# Catch React Native fetch error without halting the app with red screen

Tags: react-native

I am making a React Native function that pulls the HTML of a webpage. It works fine if the URL exists and I receive a 200 status code. However, when I put a wrong url in there (something that would receive a 404 error), it displays a red screen that says "Network request failed." I'd like to catch the error without the whole app halting and display an alert to the user. How can I go about doing that?

```
    fetchEvents() {
       fetch('http://www.wrongurl.com', {
         method: 'GET',
         redirect: 'follow'
       })
       .then(function(response) {
           if (response.status == 200) {
               let responseText = JSON.stringify(response.text());
               console.log(responseText);
           }
         else throw new Error('HTTP response status not code 200 as expected.');
       })
        .catch(function(error) {
           console.error(error);
           return error;
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I solved this, making graceful errors that don't crash the app using promises:

In my API service class:

```
  fetchEvents() {
    let thisCurrentAPIService = this;

    return new Promise(
      function (resolve, reject) {
        fetch('http://www.wrongurl.com');
        .then(
          function(response) {
            if (response.ok) {    
              let responseText = JSON.stringify(response.text());
              console.log(responseText);
            }
            else {
              reject(new Error(`Unable to retrieve events.\nInvalid response received - (${response.status}).`));
            }
          }
        )
        .catch(
          function(error) {
            reject(new Error(`Unable to retrieve events.\n${error.message}`));
          }
        );
      }
    ); 
  }
```

Then I call it from my React Component. If I receive an error, I create the alert there.

```
      this.state.apiService.fetchEvents()
      .then(
      function (value) {
        console.log('Contents: ' + value);
      },
      function (reason) {
        Alert.alert(`${reason.message}`);
      });
```

Answer (score 5):

Hilarious, three years almost and no proper answer still. 
However,   `console.error(error)`  is what actually causing the app to throw a red screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Alert component from react-native.

```
fetchEvents() {
   fetch('http://www.wrongurl.com', {
     method: 'GET',
     redirect: 'follow'
   })
   .then(function(response) {
       if (response.status == 200) {
           let responseText = JSON.stringify(response.text());
           console.log(responseText);
       }
     else throw new Error('HTTP response status not code 200 as expected.');
   })
    .catch(function(error) {
       Alert.alert(error);   // Using this line
   });
}
```

But I prefer using toast like on Android than alert.

Comment: This code is inside a Javascript APIService class so I'm unable to alert from there. I'd like to be able to throw an error to the RN Component that calls it but doing a throw just results in a red screen.

Comment: else {
    let error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
}

Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

console.warn('This is my error');

If this is simply for dev it might help. It explicitly uses the little warning toast to provide whatever feedback you need. Note: this is definitely not for production use.

Answer (score 0):

Add following in app **index.js** file

```
console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false;
```